# Android Studio 3.1.3 does not show layout desing preview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

It has passed some time since the last time I have created a new project in android studio and today when I did it the android studio does not show anything from the layout preview. Its a blank window and says "nothing to show".

I already tried;

updated the sdks tools,
cleaned the project and rebuild it,
invalidated and restarted caches,
theme changes,
and still nothing.

**Solution**

now i am using **mac**.

Comment: Have you tried with Force Refresh Layout?

Comment: @ramSuthakar yes i tried,still nothing.

Comment: same i was facing this i just downgrade 3.1.3 to 3.0.1. now its working completely fine.

Comment: @ssdeno have you upgrade your gradle into 4.4, "services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip" like this way?

Comment: @RamSuthakar updated but is still same

Comment: Could you please post the code of your layout-file? If not, please carefully check your layout-file for any incompatibilities.

Comment: @ssdeno create a new layout and add one textview in that view and check whether it will be working fine or not, sometimes our layout contains error it shouldn't showing, please try this way once

Answer (score 1):

as my experience, switch to "Design".click "force refresh layout"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you update classpath

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'

}
```

Comment: Restart your computer or android studio sometimes this simple hack works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, **switch to your Design/Text tab in layout editor**. And check the preview window. Preview will be there.

I don't know how this works but I frequently using this hack when my preview isn't working since I upgraded to *android studio 3.1.3*.

[image: Android studio - design/text view]

**PS:** This hack only applies to empty preview (none of the elements or menu items or options or messages are visible in the preview pane).

Answer (score 0):

please replace

```
compileSdkVersion 28
buildToolsVersion '28.0.0'
targetSdkVersion 28
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-beta01'
```

with

```
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
targetSdkVersion 27
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

[screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvCIj.png)

click on the Eye icon in the selected area, in the pop-up window
enable `Show Layout Decorations`.

If the magnet next to the eye icon is active, make it inactive.

Have a nice day.