# Android Studio 3.5.3 does not show layout preview

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.5.3

I'm using Android Studio 3.5.3

It has passed some time since the last time I've created a new project in Android Studio and today when I did it the Android Studio does not show anything from the layout preview. Its a blank window and says *nothing to show*.

I've already

- updated the sdks tools
- cleaned the project and rebuild it
- invalidated and restarted caches

and still nothing.

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50792203/android-studio-3-1-3-does-not-show-layout-desing-preview or https://inneka.com/programming/android/android-studio-does-not-show-layout-preview/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio 3.1.3 does not show layout desing preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50792203/android-studio-3-1-3-does-not-show-layout-desing-preview)